# How to pop up an alert from a mysql result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am looking around this all day but cant find out a way.

Basically I have a html page with Jquery function that send data to a php file to retrieve data from a database.

Retrieving data to the html page works fine.

What I am trying to do is run a comparison between the value that is fetched from database and a set limit.

This is what I have so far.

Html file

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function check(str1) {
      if (str1 == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php?q=" + str1, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    Core Arm number:</br>
    <input type="number" id="Arm" name="Arm" onchange="check(this.value)">
    </br>
  </form>
  <br>
  </div>
  <div id="txtHint"><b>info will be listed here...</b>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and PHP file

```
    <?php

$q = intval($_GET['q']);
echo $q."<br>";
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Admin";
$dbname = "coredb";
$tbname= "ArmTable";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()."<br>");
}
echo "Connected successfully <br>";
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SleCount FROM ".$tbname." WHERE CoreArm = '123456'"));
// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>'; 

    if ($row['SleCount']>=2)
echo "Exeeded Count ".$row['SleCount']." Segregate arm for Sleeve change. <script type='text/javascript'> alert('segregate');</script> <br><br><br>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Also if you know a better way let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So, after re-reading I got it.
In **php** replace this

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';`
```

with this:

```
echo 'message successfully sent';
```

***same with the other echo

Then in **javascript**, this

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

with this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

---

Should work (not tested)

Comment: thx for reply. That kind of works. this always brings an alert box even if alert box is empty. in php file I have an if statement that compares if the value from database is 2 or greater. how to bring alert box only if condition is true?

Comment: Just create a variable in php in which you put the condition result, 0 or 1. The thing is you need to get both the message and the condition to javascript. For example format the message like this "condition||message". You use the two bars "||" to split the string in javascript. Then test the condition again (if true) and alert the message.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you send the condition and message to javascript. can you do an if statement to display the alert or not? Can you show me an example?